# Passing arguments to filter function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

JQuery allow to use function as .filter() argument to test each element in the set

```
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return (index > 3) && (index < 10);
  })
.css( "background-color", "red" );
```

how I can to pass arguments to this function so it looks like

```
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index, min, max ) {
    return (index > min) && (index < max);
  })
.css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Answer (score 8):

Declaring the variables before calling filter should work just fine

```
var min = 3, max = 19;
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return (index > min) && (index < max);
  })
.css( "background-color", "red" );
```

There is no need to pass in arguments in this case.